# Banach Space, operator and orthogonality

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T \in B(X,Y)$ with $X$ and $Y$  Banach spaces and $M \subseteq X$ is subspace of $X$. We suppose that:

$(i)$ For $M \subseteq X$ and $N \subseteq X'$ we always have that $M^{\bot}$ and $N^{\bot}$ are closed, and $(M^{\bot})^{\bot} = \overline{M}$ and $(N^{\bot})^{\bot} \supseteq \overline{N}$.

$(ii)$ $X'/(M^{\bot}) \cong M'$ (via linear bijective isometry)

$(iii)$ If $M$ is closed then  $(X/M)' \cong M^{\bot}$ (via linear bijective)

$(iv)$ $Ker(T) = (R(T^{*}))^{\bot}$

$(v)$  $Ker(T^{*}) = (R(T))^{\bot}$

$(vi)$ $\phi: X/Ker(T) \to R(T)$ given by $\phi([x]) = T(x)$ is a linear bijective, so $X/Ker(T) \cong R(T)$ (via linear bijective).

I want to **prove that**: $(Ker(T))^{\bot} = \overline{R(T^{*})}$

My try:

By $(iv)$ we have that $Ker(T)^{\bot} = ((R(T^{*}))^{\bot})^{\bot}$. Using $(i)$ we obtain that   $\overline{R(T^{*})} \subseteq Ker(T)^{\bot}$.

$(Ker(T))^{\bot} \cong (X/Ker(T))'$ by $(iii)$, because $Ker(T)$ is closed.

$(X/Ker(T))' \cong (R(T))'$, becuase $X/Ker(T) \cong R(T)$ (via linear bijective) by $(vi)$

$(R(T))' \cong Y'/(R(T)^{\bot})$ by $(ii)$

$Y'/(R(T)^{\bot})  =  Y'/(Ker(T^{*}))$ because $Ker(T^{*}) = R(T)^{\bot}$ by $(v)$

$Y'/ (Ker(T^{*})) \cong R(T^{*})$, because $Y'/Ker(T^{*}) \cong R(T^{*})$ (via linear bijective) by $(vi)$.

But $R(T^{*}) \subseteq \overline{R(T^{*})} \subseteq  (Ker(T))^{\bot}$ and  $R(T^{*}) \cong (Ker(T))^{\bot}$ (via linear bijective), so this subspaces have the same dimension, hence $R(T^{*}) = (Ker(T))^{\bot}$. But it's false, because we don't suppose that $R(T^{*})$ is closed.

Where am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: You only have a continuous bijection $X/\ker T \to R(T)$. Unless $R(T)$ is closed, the inverse of that is not continuous, and then the injection $R(T)' \hookrightarrow (X/\ker T)'$ is not surjective.

Comment: Thank you, @DanielFischer. I found in Brezis, Analyse fonctionnelle (1987), pg. 29, that we only have that $\overline{R(T^{*})} \subseteq Ker(T)^{\bot}$. The converse is true, if $X$ is reflexive.

Comment: Generally, $(\ker T)^{\perp}$ is the weak$^{\ast}$-closure of $R(T^{\ast})$. If $X$ is reflexive, then the weak$^{\ast}$ topology on $X^{\ast}$ is identical with the weak topology on $X^{\ast}$. Since subspaces are convex, a subspace of $X^{\ast}$ is closed if and only if it is weakly closed, so if $X$ is reflexive, we always have $\overline{R(T^{\ast})} = (\ker T)^{\perp}$. If $X$ is not reflexive, that happens for some $T$, but not all (generally at least; I can't guarantee that there isn't a non-reflexive Banach space $X$ so

Comment: that $\overline{R(T^{\ast})} = (\ker T)^{\perp}$ for all $T\in B(X,Y)$ where $Y$ is some Banach space). The closed range theorem tells us that $R(T^{\ast})$ is weak$^{\ast}$-closed whenever $R(T)$ is closed, but it doesn't tell us when $\overline{R(T^{\ast})}$ is weak$^{\ast}$-closed if $R(T)$ isn't closed.